# Determining statusbar orientation

Tags: ios

I am wanting to detect where the status bar is on my current view in order to determine which segue to perform. I know the preferred way to do this is to determine the device orientation, but there are two problems with this approach for me:

1.) If the device is not angled far enough away from vertical or horizontal then there is no device orientation detected and the segue doesn't happen

2.) Under certain conditions I am going to "lock" the display orientation such that even though the physical device orientation is landscape the screen is going to be locked to portrait and I will want to perform the portrait segue I have created.

The problem is that the " [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation = " is not returning the actual orientation of the status bar. Is there not an easy way to detect this? Otherwise I am going to have to write a bunch of messy code to keep track of this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried: `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]`?

Note:

Depending on the design of your app it might be necessary to call `[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]`. If you do that, make sure to call `[[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]` at some point.

If that's not sufficient for your purpose I guess you have to manually check the accelerometer. Take a look at: [Handling Motion Events](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html) for more info on how that's done.

Comment: Device orientation is not what I want though. What I am basing my segue on is WHERE is the statusbar located (i.e. top for portrait or left or right for landscape). There will be times when I have locked the image rotation on the screen such that even though the device is physically in landscape the image on screen is actually in portrait and that is what the I need to know before calling the segue. I was hoping the statusbarOrientation would give me that, but it doesn't update every time when rotated...

Comment: I don't see a problem with that. You **know** when you lock the rotation, just check which orientation you lock it in and use it to determine which segue to call. If it's not locked use the deviceOrientation.

Comment: The other problem is that not all orientations are recognizable by the OS. You have to be far enough away from horizontal or vertical in order to have a valid orientation. Otherwise it returns no orientation and the segue doesn't happen (i.e. my button does nothing). So that won't work...